# Is there any SMS/MMS server for LAN environment

Tags: lan, tcpip, sms, mms

I am looking for a solution to send SMS/MMS message to mobile device from desktop or browser in LAN environment.  As such, it is most probably using TCP/IP protocol to transmit request/response.

The server may attach to a GSM device with SIM card attached.  An server application would then start accept the request from any LAN client and convey the SMS/MMS to one or more recipients.  The server may log all requests for further traffic analysis in later stage.

Is there any solution that able to perform what I describe here.  Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app on the android market that I think does what you want.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shroomyCorp.PeerChat
It works on lan to, but I'm not sure if you can connect it with a desktop. Perhaps you should mail the dev, it might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You say "may attach" to a GSM device. Do you have to do it this way?

The way I do this is to have an account with a bulk SMS provider out in the "cloud" and then applications running on our systems use this provider to send SMS.

SMS recipient can be anywhere.

Provider gives us HTTP (or HTTPS) APIs to send the messages ...

Of course it means that you need a connection to the internet to be able to send SMS messages.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for SMS alerts through Nagios it's a fairly simple setup and used quite often with server monitoring. Alot of guides are available but I would suggest start at[Tux mobile](http://tuxmobil.org/phones_linux_sms.html). That link has just about everything you need to get running. However you do have a few choices:

1. you can setup desktop with your preferred flavor of Linux (I used ubuntu 8.10) and connect to a sms gateway on the web like Liam mentions. The version of linux you install may vary based on the SMS client, look over the solutions in the above link and find the one you feel most comfortable with: check  out the UI, the community, pricing.
2. You can setup a linux box and hook a mobile phone to it [check here](http://tuxmobil.org/phones_linux.html) for a list of linux compatible phones. Again clients are listed on the link provided above.
3. Get yourself a hardware sms gateway like [Fox Box](http://www.smsfoxbox.com/). They will provide tech support and documentation to get it setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send an email.

```
* AT&T: number@txt.att.net
* Qwest: number@qwestmp.com
* T-Mobile: number@tmomail.net
* Verizon: number@vtext.com
* Sprint: number@messaging.sprintpcs.com or number@pm.sprint.com
* Virgin Mobile: number@vmobl.com
* Nextel: number@messaging.nextel.com
* Alltel: number@message.alltel.com
* Metro PCS: number@mymetropcs.com
* Powertel: number@ptel.com
* Suncom: number@tms.suncom.com
* U.S. Cellular: number@email.uscc.net
```